# Card Flip effect

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, transition, effect, flip, cclayer

I’m starting my development in Cocos2D and I wish to make this card effect you can see on the 0:26 second in this movie:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7gn7Obeykm8
Is there any special Cocos2D Transition for this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like CCTransitionFlipX

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_transition_flip_x.html

Comment: Okay, I see. But there is not light effect. I think it's something deeper.

Comment: Flipping the whole scene is through CCTRansitionFlipX, I don't see the lighting effect.

Answer (score 0):

I flip card using

```
id flipx  = [CCFlipX3D actionWithDuration:1];
id flipx_back = [flipx reverse];
id delay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0];
```

[node runAction:[CCSequence actions: flipx, delay, flipx_back, nil]];

But, How can I show different image in back side of the node?

Answer (score 0):

```
            CCFlipX3D* flipx  = CCFlipX3D::create(1);
            CCActionInterval* flipx_back = flipx->reverse();
            CCDelayTime* delay = CCDelayTime::create(0);

            node->runAction(CCSequence::create(flipx, delay, flipx_back, NULL));
```